# Encrypting files within a WiX built MSI installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have a requirement to create an installer that includes third party dll's that are licensed. 
I can see a way of using custom actions to read an XML licence file to prevent sections of my installer from be able to install, but I can't prevent someone from using MSIExec to extract those files anyway.

Is there a way of encrypting the files within WiX to prevent their extraction by such tools?

Or is the answer to use custom actions to decrypt the files myself after storing them as encrypted? Which I assume will make the uninstall/upgrade more tricky?

Comment: I think you need to use custom actions or use a more secure licensing method.

Comment: Are you trying to protect the files from being extracted by customers who are not going to have those files installed as part of installation? If protecting these files is that important you might think of pulling them into separate installer that you more tightly control distribution of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to write a custom action and it *will* make things more complicated. :)

Note, you are entering an arms race trying to protect data in a declarative format. The data is there and it's just a matter of transforming it to find it. Putting the transform in DLL makes it a bit harder for people to see the transformation but ultimately, the bad guys will see it if they want to.